# How does the fallback mechanism of DownloadFileshareArtifacts@1 work?

Tags: azure-devops, on-premises-instances

Recently i stumbled over the log outout of the [DownloadFileshareArtifacts@1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-fileshare-artifacts-v1?view=azure-pipelines) task. I was a bit surprised that it was not using my expected artifact during the deployment, but has choosen a different package with the same git commit.

```
##[section]get-artifacts > download package is started.
==============================================================================
Task : Download artifacts from file share
Description : This is used to download artifacts from a file share such as "\\Share\Drop".
Version : 1.205.0
Author : Microsoft Corporation
Help : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-fileshare-artifacts
==============================================================================
Artifact "V2.0.74-patch02-75085e9" is downloaded from \\my\fileshare\2.0.74-
patch02\2023-12-07-V2.0.74-patch02-75085e9.

The directory "\\my\fileshare\2.0.74-patch02\2023-12-07-V2.0.74-patch02-75085e9" 
does not exist. Fallback to the parent directory: \\my\fileshare\2.0.74-patch02

Download from "2023-12-07-V2.0.74-patch02-75085e9\2023-12-08-V2.0.74-patch02-
75085e9\2023-12-08-V2.0.74-patch02-75085e9.zip" to "C:\_AGENTS\06\_work\1\package\2023-
12-07-V2.0.74-patch02-75085e9\2023-12-08-V2.0.74-patch02-75085e9\2023-12-08-V2.0.74-
patch02-75085e9.zip" is executed.

# Translated from german output, maybe not 100% accurate
```

The good thing is that he selected a new build with the same Git commit.
But will that always be the case?

I have read the documentation but i did not find anything about a fallback mechanis.
Does someone has more insights?

My current pipeline definition is as simple as it could be i would say:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: package 
    source: pck-foobar
    branch: develop

[...]

  - download: package
    displayName: "get-artifacts > download package"
```

---

Answers to questions from comments:

1. No we have different agents for build and deployment.
   Building happens via an agent-pool and deployment happens via an environment-agent. Both have access rights to the file-share.
2. 2023-12-08-V2.0.74-patch02-75085e9.zip was created through a scheduled build.
   I would say the file was not there, but it looks like it is now. Which is quite
   strange. I could swear two days ago the folder was empty, because i have checked that and
   it would be even stranger if azure would have skipped an existing file.
3. Task configuration for publishing:

```
task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
displayName: 'publish-artifacts $(Build.BuildNumber) ${{ parameters.targetPath }}'
inputs:
  PathtoPublish: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
  ArtifactName: $(Build.BuildNumber)
  ArtifactType: FilePath
  TargetPath: ${{ parameters.targetPath }}
```

Comment: 1. Is the agent you use to publish artifacts and the agent that downloads artifacts the same? If not, try using the agent for publishing artifact to download the artifact. Then it should download the artifact from your shared path. According to my tests, if the agent that downloads the artifact does not have permission to access `shared folder/artifactname`, it will fallback to the parent directory. 2. Could you please let me know how `2023-12-07-V2.0.74-patch02-75085e9\2023-12-08-V2.0.74-patch02-
75085e9\2023-12-08-V2.0.74-patch02-75085e9.zip` was created? Is this file in your shared folder?

Comment: 3. Would you please share the task configuration of the publish artifact task in your `pck-foobar` pipeline?

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT i have updated my question with the answers for your questions. Maybe azure is smart enough to detect builds with the same git commit and just optimize storage on the file-share? So an artifact build with the same pipeline, the same git commit wins over 'older' artifacts which are basically the same?

Comment: 1. Please go to your shared folder, delete **all** files in this folder. Then manually run your publish artifact pipeline. Then check whether you can see the artifact in the shared folder. If you can see it, run your download artifact pipeline to see what's the result. 2. Based on my test, if the target artifact does not exist in the shared folder, the pipeline will download all other files that already exist in the shared folder.

Comment: I am guessing artifact "2023-12-07-V2.0.74-patch02-75085e9" was not successfully published to your shared folder, and there is already the file `2023-12-08-V2.0.74-patch02-
75085e9\2023-12-08-V2.0.74-patch02-75085e9.zip` in your shared folder, so the artifact actually downloaded is it. If this is the case, you can do a simple test by adding any file to your shared folder, then run the download artifact pipeline, and the new file will also be downloaded.

Comment: have you tried my suggestions to narrow down the issue? Has your artifact been successfully published to the shared folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my test, if the target artifact does not exist in the shared folder, the pipeline will download all other files that already exist in the shared folder.

I am guessing the artifact "2023-12-07-V2.0.74-patch02-75085e9" was not successfully published to your shared folder, and there is already the file 2023-12-08-V2.0.74-patch02- 75085e9\2023-12-08-V2.0.74-patch02-75085e9.zip in your shared folder, so the artifact actually downloaded is it. If this is the case, you can do a simple test by adding any file to your shared folder, then run the download artifact pipeline, and the new file will also be downloaded.